# CacheDependency: Absolute path information is required

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a site which displays job vacancies. The data is provided as an RSS feed by a 3rd party.

I would like to store the data in our server cache with a cache dependency so the data is refreshed when the feed is updated.

When the cache dependency is set to use the remote feed file I get the error `Absolute path information is required.` when inserting to cache.

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("JobFeed", jobs, new CacheDependency("http://[AddressRemoved]/rssfeed.aspx"));
```

Is there any way to allow it to use a remote file instead of a local one? Could I use Virutal Path Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, because .net framework is unable to detect when that feed changes. You have to write code that will check from time to time for changes in the feed and update the cache.

You can set the cache entry to expire after a period, and when the entry is expired reload the feed and update the cache.